# How can I extract tweets using tweepy

Tags: python-3.x, api, twitter, data-science

My Questions is If I want to get Tweets based on a specific Keyword , What I should have done or How I can get it .

### i use latest Python and anaconda Distribution
I use Jupyter Notebook
This is what I wrote

[image: This is my code]

My Questions is If I want to get Tweets based on a specific Keyword , What I should have done or How I can get it.

Comment: did you mean to extract from hashtag, or the keyword inside the tweet?

Comment: I mean hashtag. I think I am having issue from here                                         
tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name="-------------", count=2000)
print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))                                          This code is basically extracting from ID . I want to extract from hashtag  . Cheers

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948628/how-to-take-all-tweets-in-a-hashtag-with-tweepy This may help you.

Comment: Thanks mate , My current code works fine with any Hash tag Except " #LetsTaxThis" . What could be the issue do you  think. Cheers

Comment: You have space before the hash `" #LetsTaxThis"`. I'm not sure if that's causing the problem. `"#LetsTaxThis"`, can you try doing this instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the user id, you don't need to use `api.user_timeline` as it is user based. You should try to use the api search:

```
query = "#WhateverHashtagIWant"
my_tweet_list = []
for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q=query).pages():
    my_tweet_list.extend(page)
```

Comment: My current code works fine with any Hash tag Except " #LetsTaxThis" . What could be the issue. you guys think. Cheers

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Does it return you an error? If so, which one?